# 要素がlist型であるpandasのdataframeをndarrayの２次元配列にしたい

Tags: python, pandas, 機械学習, numpy

dataframe e.g)

```
date                                                vec
2019-01-04  [-0.08072768, -0.061041858, 0.09872102]
2019-01-04  [-0.07853928, -0.058681224, 0.10971683]
```

こういったdataframeがあった場合に、列vecのみ取り出し、変換して(2,3)の２次元ndarrayに変換したいのですが、うまく行きません。
実行環境: python 3.7.3

できれば、pythonの方でfor文回して、dataframe １行ずつとって、concatenateするような方法は避けたいです。。

試したこと:

```
    df = df['vec']
    array = df.values
```

これだと、arrayには(3,)のベクトルがつ連続するという型になってしまいます。
なのでarray.shapeの出力は(2,),array[0].shapeの出力は(3,)のようになってしまいます。

Comment: `numpy.vstack` を使うのはどうでしょうか。`np.vstack(df.vec)`

Comment: @metropolis まさにそれでした。。
解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @berry_summer さん> もし解決された場合は、解決した方法を回答して投稿し、質問を解決済みにしていただけませんか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array = np.vstack(df.vec)
```

により解決できました。